# why is this OCMock verify failing?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ocmock

Not sure if I'm using OCMocks correctly, or if it's because I'm using the cocoapods version and not the .lib file.

Here's the test(s)

```
#import "MWViewControllerTests.h"
#import "MWViewController.h"
#import "OCMockObject.h"
#import "MWGoogleTrends.h"
#import "OCMockRecorder.h"

@implementation MWViewControllerTests {

    MWViewController *vcSUT;
    id googleTrends;
    NSArray *trends;
}

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    vcSUT = [[MWViewController alloc] init];
    googleTrends = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[MWGoogleTrends class]];
    vcSUT.googleTrends = googleTrends;
    trends = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"trend1", @"trend2", @"trend3", nil];
    [[[googleTrends stub] andReturn:trends] getLatestTrends];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Tear-down code here.
    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)test_ViewDidLoadShouldCallGoogleTrends_getLatestTrends
{
    [[googleTrends expect] getLatestTrends];
    [vcSUT view];  // calls loadView
    [googleTrends verify];
}
```

@end

Here's the VC:

```
@implementation MWViewController {

    NSArray *_trends;
}

@synthesize googleTrends;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _trends = [self.googleTrends getLatestTrends];
}
```

The googleTrends is a property in the header of course:

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) MWGoogleTrends *googleTrends;
```

I would imagine it's being invoked because the following tests below it are passing:

```
- (void)test_numRowsInTableViewShouldBeNumOfTrendsReturnedFromGetLatestTrends {

    [vcSUT view];
    int numSections = [vcSUT tableView:nil numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    STAssertEquals(numSections, 3, @"should be 3 sections");
}

- (void)test_cellForRowAtIndexPath_should_return_cell_with_trendName_as_text {

    [vcSUT view];
    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [vcSUT tableView:nil cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [vcSUT tableView:nil cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1]];
    UITableViewCell *cell3 = [vcSUT tableView:nil cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:2]];

    STAssertEquals(cell1.textLabel.text, @"trend1", @"cell text should be correct trend name");
    STAssertEquals(cell2.textLabel.text, @"trend2", @"cell text should be correct trend name");
    STAssertEquals(cell3.textLabel.text, @"trend3", @"cell text should be correct trend name");
}

@end
```

also getting this warning from the compiler, not sure if it related in any way:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/markw/Projects/XCode/OReillyCasts/MWGoogleTrends/Pods/build/Release-iphoneos'
```

Comment: What is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: OCMockObject[MWGoogleTrends]: expected method was not invoked: getLatestTrends. ETA: updated above to show that the tests below it are passing, so ViewDidLoad is being called and the stubbed results are being returned.

Comment: I think (it's been a while since I actually used OCMock) that it's because you've stubbed the method previous to setting up the expectation that the same stub method is going to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the issue is with stubbing the method.

I had to stub the method on the mock only for the test methods that needed the stub, the expectation passes when I took out the stubbing from the Setup.